# C++ Default Templated Constructor With 1 Parameter

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a BinaryNode class for use in a BinarySearchTree. When I try to test this code, and run the program below, it compiles with no errors, but when the program is run, it stops and returns:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Can anyone see my mistake?

```
#ifndef _NODE
#define _NODE 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class BinaryNode
{
    private:
        ItemType    item; //any data type
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftChild;
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightChild;
    public:
        BinaryNode();
        BinaryNode( ItemType newItem );
        void setItem(ItemType newData);
        ItemType getData()       { return item;}
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* getLeftChild()    { return leftChild; }
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* getRightChild()   { return rightChild; } 
        void setLeftChild(BinaryNode<ItemType>* newLeftPtr) { leftChild = newLeftPtr;}
        void setRightChild(BinaryNode<ItemType>* newRightPtr)   { rightChild = newRightPtr;}
        //void display(BinaryNode* rootNode);
};

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode()
{
    BinaryNode newNode;
    newNode.setItem( NULL );
    newNode.setLeftChild( nullptr);
    newNode.setRightChild( nullptr );
} 

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem)
{

    BinaryNode newNode;
    newNode.setItem( newItem );
    newNode.setLeftChild( nullptr );
    newNode.setRightChild( nullptr );
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNode<ItemType>::setItem(ItemType newData)
{
    item =  newData;
}

#endif      

******************* MAIN *************************************
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BinaryNode.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinaryNode<string> newNode("string");
    cout << newNode.getData() << endl;  
return 0;       
}

********************** ERROR ***************************

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: <iostream> and <string> are both included in main.

Comment: Your problem isn't exactly from the code shown. BTW: The implementation of your templated single argument constructor isn't correct

Comment: Show the code. Some functions are not defined in your posted code!

Comment: ill throw the whole thing up, i was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: @orangepeelsnice... No, No, No! ..Please not the whole thing (Unless its reasonably short). Just relevant shortest code that reproduces your problem. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i see, whats wrong with my single arg constructor? @WhiZTiM

Comment: @WhiZTiM updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually fairly simple:

```
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem)
{
    BinaryNode newNode;
    newNode.setItem( newItem );
    newNode.setLeftChild( nullptr );
    newNode.setRightChild( nullptr );
}
```

In your constructor which takes an `ItemType`, you create a local variable `newNode`. At the end of this scope the destructor for that object is called and thus it no longer exists.

**Edit:** But the reason that you get a segmentation fault is due to an infinite recursion as explained in opetroch's post:

> Your constructor will cause a stack overflow by doing an infinite recursion.
>
> BinaryNode::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem) creates a local
>   variable for which the default constructor will be called, which in
>   turn will create another local variable for which again the default
>   constructor will be called, continuing until the you get a stack
>   overflow.

The constructor should instead look like:

```
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem)
{
    setItem( newItem );
    setLeftChild( nullptr );
    setRightChild( nullptr );
}
```

Because an implicit 'this' pointer is passed to the constructor and all other member functions, which point to the object that the function was called on. This is the object that you need to modify to get your desired behaviour. You can even make it really explicit by writing your constructor as follows:

```
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem)
{
    this->setItem( newItem );
    this->setLeftChild( nullptr );
    this->setRightChild( nullptr );
}
```

Comment: -1. The constructor initializes a local variable but the member variable item is of type std::string. It will be an empty string, nothing wrong with accessing it.

Comment: I agree with you about how the constructor should look like, however your statement that the member variable doesn't exist at the end of the scope is not correct.

Comment: wait so i don't need to delcare an object in my node class, it is actually already declare in main?

Comment: @GlühwürmchenimHimmel Thank you, it works. It would seem i'm still trying to hammer out the details with oop.

Comment: @orangepeelsnice an implicit 'this' pointer is passed to the constructor and all other member functions, which point to the object that the function was called on

Comment: @GlühwürmchenimHimmel ok as it is changed now it doesn't contain any wrong statements but it doesn't explain why the error happens. I think you could explain that bit in your answer. I would be happy to remove the downvote, but it doesn't allow me unless the answer is edited :)

Comment: well, it wouldn't let me remove the downvote, it's your call :) Anyway everyone is happy now I guess, goodnight.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor will cause a stack overflow by doing an infinite recursion.

BinaryNode::BinaryNode(ItemType newItem) creates a local variable
for which the default constructor will be called, which in turn will create another local variable for which again the default constructor will be called, continuing until the you get a stack overflow.

You should change your constructor acccording to  Glühwürmchen im Himmel's post.